# Tensorflow: RaggedTensor.from_tensor flattening values from all arrays into one array, instead of preserving original number of arrays

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensorflow-datasets

In the official documentation, `RaggedTensor.from_tensor` will work something like this.

```
x = [[1, 3, -1, -1], [2, -1, -1, -1], [4, 5, 8, 9]]
print(tf.RaggedTensor.from_tensor(x, padding=-1))
```

Output:

```
 <tf.RaggedTensor [[1, 3], [2], [4, 5, 8, 9]]>
```

Preserving the original number of arrays.

However, when working with a batch outputted by the dataset api iterator, it flattens it to one array. Here is the key parts of the code.

```
dataset = dataset.padded_batch(3, padded_shapes=([None],[None]), padding_values=(tf.constant(-1, dtype=tf.int64)
                                                 ,tf.constant(-1, dtype=tf.int64)))
iterator = dataset.make_one_shot_iterator()
i, data = iterator.get_next()

data2= tf.RaggedTensor.from_tensor(data, padding=-1)

with tf.Session() as sess:
    print(sess.run([ data, data2 ]))
    print(sess.run([ data, data2 ]))
    print(sess.run([ data, data2 ]))
```

Here is the output

```
[array([[ 0,  1,  2,  3, -1],
       [ 2,  3,  4, -1, -1],
       [ 3,  6,  5,  4,  3]]), tf.RaggedTensorValue(values=array([0, 1, 2, 3, 2, 3, 4, 3, 6, 5, 4, 3]), row_splits=array([ 0,  4,  7, 12]))]
[array([[ 3,  9, -1, -1],
       [ 0,  1,  2,  3],
       [ 2,  3,  4, -1]]), tf.RaggedTensorValue(values=array([3, 9, 0, 1, 2, 3, 2, 3, 4]), row_splits=array([0, 2, 6, 9]))]
[array([[ 3,  6,  5,  4,  3],
       [ 3,  9, -1, -1, -1],
       [ 0,  1,  2,  3, -1]]), tf.RaggedTensorValue(values=array([3, 6, 5, 4, 3, 3, 9, 0, 1, 2, 3]), row_splits=array([ 0,  5,  7, 11]))]
```

Here is the full code to the minimal example to reproduce the results

```
!pip install -q tf-nightly
import math
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf

#Generate Test data
cells = np.array([[0,1,2,3], [2,3,4], [3,6,5,4,3], [3,9]])
mells = np.array([[0], [2], [3], [9]])
print(cells)

#Write test data to tf.records file
writer = tf.python_io.TFRecordWriter('test.tfrecords')
for index in range(mells.shape[0]):
    example = tf.train.Example(features=tf.train.Features(feature={
        'num_value':tf.train.Feature(int64_list=tf.train.Int64List(value=mells[index])),
        'list_value':tf.train.Feature(int64_list=tf.train.Int64List(value=cells[index]))
    }))
    writer.write(example.SerializeToString())
writer.close()

#Open tfrecords file and generate batch from data 
filenames = ["test.tfrecords"]
dataset = tf.data.TFRecordDataset(filenames)
def _parse_function(example_proto):
    keys_to_features = {'num_value':tf.VarLenFeature(tf.int64),
                        'list_value':tf.VarLenFeature(tf.int64)}
    parsed_features = tf.parse_single_example(example_proto, keys_to_features)
    return tf.sparse.to_dense(parsed_features['num_value']), \
           tf.sparse.to_dense(parsed_features['list_value'])
# Parse the record into tensors.
dataset = dataset.map(_parse_function)
# Shuffle the dataset
dataset = dataset.shuffle(buffer_size=1)
# Repeat the input indefinitly
dataset = dataset.repeat()  
# Generate batches
dataset = dataset.padded_batch(3, padded_shapes=([None],[None]), padding_values=(tf.constant(-1, dtype=tf.int64)
                                                 ,tf.constant(-1, dtype=tf.int64)))
iterator = dataset.make_one_shot_iterator()
i, data = iterator.get_next()

#Remove padding
data2= tf.RaggedTensor.from_tensor(data, padding=-1)

#Print data
with tf.Session() as sess:
    sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())
    print(sess.run([ data, data2 ]))
    print(sess.run([ data, data2 ]))
    print(sess.run([ data, data2 ]))
```

Here is the official Tensorflow Guide to ragged tensors

https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/ragged_tensors

And official Tensorflow documentation

https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r1.13/api_docs/python/tf/RaggedTensor

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you discovered, the `RaggedTensor`s are not actually getting flattened.  Internally, a 2D `RaggedTensor` is encoded using two Tensors/arrays: one containing a flat list of values, and the other containing row splits.  For more details about how `RaggedTensor`s are encoded using underlying tensors/arrays, see: https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/ragged_tensors#raggedtensor_encoding

The confusion was probably coming from the way that RaggedTensors get displayed when printing.  Python has two string conversion methods: `__str__` and `__repr__`.  `__str__` gets used if you just print a value by itself, and `__repr__` gets used if that value is embedded in some larger structure (such as a list).

For RaggedTensorValue, the `__str__` method returns `"<tf.RaggedTensorValue %s>" % self.to_list()`.  I.e., it will show you the value formatted as a list.  But the `__repr__` method returns `"tf.RaggedTensorValue(values=%r, row_splits=%r)" % (self._values, self._row_splits)`.  I.e., it will show you the underlying numpy arrays that are used to encode the RaggedTensorValue.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out it's not flattening it, not exactly sure how it works but it looks like by keeping track of where the row breaks are, and then executes them when evaluated.

`tf.RaggedTensorValue(values=array([3, 6, 5, 4, 3, 3, 9, 0, 1, 2, 3]), row_splits=array([ 0,  5,  7, 11]))]`

'row_splits' keeps track of where to split the rows.

Here are some results with eager execution.

```
i, data = iterator.get_next()

#Remove padding
data2= tf.RaggedTensor.from_tensor(data, padding=-1)
print(data2)

i, data = iterator.get_next()

#Remove padding
data2= tf.RaggedTensor.from_tensor(data, padding=-1)
print(data2)

i, data = iterator.get_next()

#Remove padding
data2= tf.RaggedTensor.from_tensor(data, padding=-1)
print(data2)

i, data = iterator.get_next()

#Remove padding
data2= tf.RaggedTensor.from_tensor(data, padding=-1)
print(data2)
```

results

```
<tf.RaggedTensor [[3, 9], [0, 1, 2, 3], [2, 3, 4]]>
<tf.RaggedTensor [[3, 6, 5, 4, 3], [3, 9], [0, 1, 2, 3]]>
<tf.RaggedTensor [[2, 3, 4], [3, 6, 5, 4, 3], [3, 9]]>
<tf.RaggedTensor [[0, 1, 2, 3], [2, 3, 4], [3, 6, 5, 4, 3]]>
```